# Rails Admin - making session helper var available to config

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building my first rails app and don't know how to make a helper instance variable available to RailsAdmin.config. I would like to only allow access to rails admin if the currently logged in user has admin privileges. I'm not sure where the RailsAdmin.config code should go but I currently have it in environment.rb. When I login I'm getting a undefined local variable or method error for current_user. Thanks for any help.

***environment.rb***

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

***sessions_helper.rb***

```
module SessionsHelper
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

***application_controller.rb***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RailsAdmin no longer inherits from your base `ApplicationController` for its controllers ([this commit](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/commit/c8e697a65c506e6129684d31f738c7eea34f9300#diff-4)). You can do this in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
require "rails_admin/application_controller"

module RailsAdmin
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    include SessionsHelper
  end
end
```

See [RailsAdmin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Declarative-Authorization)

Or I think you can do this as well to keep the old behaviour:

```
config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'
```

See this [changelog](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/ae2962ca9e2e229589e5f6a80a03bca72cf18312/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Thanks, the second method worked. The first method gives this error `<module:RailsAdmin>': superclass mismatch for class ApplicationController (TypeError).